# Is there a method to retrieve the file name of a class?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a method to retrieve the file name of a class?

Specifically I would like to create a static method (CreateLink) in a base class (BasePage) to automatically return the path and filename of the page called.

I code in .C# ASP.NET

```
private const string TEMPLATE =
    "~/One.aspx";

public static HyperLink CreateLink()
{
    HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
    link.Text = "Click here";
    link.NavigateUrl = String.Format(TEMPLATE);
    return link;
}
```

Is it possible to avoid the use of TEMPLATE hardcoded variable? Is it possible to retrieve the One.aspx path from file name and location?

Comment: Which page do you want the path to?

Comment: your question is not clear, you want to access the file name for a given path or you want to extract file name from a request variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the path of the page currently request by checking [`HttpContext.Current.Request.Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.path%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Request.Path get the path of the current request. I would like to be able to retrieve the path of the next request. :-)

Answer (score 2):

what do you mean by file name of a class? You need to get the file name from a given path? Try this

```
Path.GetFileName(HttpContext.Current.Request.Path)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the actual code-behind filename using reflection you can use the following:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace(true);
StackFrame frame = stackTrace.GetFrame(0);
string s = frame.GetFileName();
```

Comment: Point taken, but it does answer the "Is there a method to retrieve the file name of a class?" part of the question, though I should have read the whole question more carefully...